# best prebuilt components for login page and user module for react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a new mobile app in RN which will require a login page.  I can build all of this from scratch of course but I wanted to find out, based on the latest technology and trends, the most common tools, technologies and aproaches that RN devs are currently using for this.  Essentially, if you were to create a brand new mobile app in RN today, what approaches and components would you use?  My preference is to implement the login module for free, except for my labor, unless there's a high quality aternative for a few dollars per month, which saves a significant amount of implementation/troubleshooting/overhead/etc that a lot of RN devs are currently leveraging.

Comment: Firebase is a common tool that combines many server side features easy to implement out of the box. https://medium.com/@eng.sohaddader/start-with-react-native-firebase-authentication-and-realtime-database-services-466359d577c6

Comment: aws amplify is also a good option https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite open ended but here you go.

### UI Components

You need your new app to look good and user friendly, these two are what i would almost always choose between they provide all the components you need to have an elegant app and are light-weight dependencies:

1. [`react-native-paper`](https://reactnativepaper.com/)
2. [`react-native-elements`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/)

### State Management

Almost always you will need to share certain values, arrays, objects, etc. between components, to achieve this i usually decide between:

1. [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) - if i am building a simple small scale application.
2. [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) - if the application needs to be highly scalable and need enable certain features Redux can help with (i.e. offline application usage, etc.)

**Note: i would highly recommend you using Redux for state management, true the boilerplate is a pain but it will help you greatly on the long run.**

### Miscellaneous

1. [Expo](https://expo.io) - Pretty much most of my applications use expo platform, i would say your application development timeline is cut by 1/3 using it, however the greatest downside would be the inability to integrate native modules with it like how you use `link` in a normal react native application.
2. [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) - For any HTTP related requests
3. [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) - For handling my application routing and navigation

### Bonus

If you are actually just starting a new application, i have just finished setting up a quick boilerplate that pretty much uses all the technologies i mentioned above. as well as pre-setup authentication flow, theming (Light and Dark theme) and some extra stuff!

Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/AbdeenM/react-native-expo-kit) :)

Hope this Helps!